# Transforming grammar for predictive parsing

Tags: parsing, theory

Is the following grammar suitable for predictive parsing, or is their an algorithm to modify the grammar to make it suitable for predictive parsing?

```
number = digit digit_or_sep* digit | digit
digit_or_sep = '0'..'9' | '_'
digit = '0'..'9'
```

where `*` means zero or more, and `|` divides the different choices.

I have written a backtracking parser that works fine on the above grammar, however I've read that modern parsers are mostly predictive parsers these days and backtracking parsers are rarely used. Backtracking parsers need to rewind the state of the parser as they backtrack which makes them less performant than predictive parsers.

Transforming the grammar above into:

```
number = digit (sep* digit+)*
sep = '_'
digit = '0'..'9'
```

where `+` means one or more.

Will make predictive parsing work because it avoids `digit_or_sep*` from consuming too many tokens before the final `digit`. But I am not sure if there is an algorithmic way to auto-transform the grammar to make it work.

**Edit:** I had a read about left factoring on google, it could be the missing piece of the puzzle I need to understand.

After a bit of left refactoring:

```
number = digit digit_or_sep* digit | digit
digit_or_sep = '0'..'9' | '_'
digit = '0'..'9'
let g = digit_or_sep g | empty
number = digit g digit | digit
let h = g digit | empty
number = digit h
h = g digit | empty
g = digit_or_sep g | empty
g = digit g | sep g | empty
h = (digit g | sep g | empty) digit | empty
h = digit g digit | sep g digit | digit | empty
h = digit h | sep g digit | empty
```

The following grammar is produced:

```
number = digit h
h = digit h | sep g digit | empty
g = digit g | sep g | empty
```

Which should be suitable for a predictive parser. But I have still not come up with an algorithm to do it yet automatically.

**Edit:** Throwing in more details of what I am trying to do. The grammar above is just an small example of grammar I'd like to transform.

I am actually parsing Kotlin:
https://github.com/clinuxrulz/parse-bolt/blob/main/src/kotlin/parser.rs

And it is working fine with the backtracking parser, but it is having performance issues. Parsing a simple function type signature "(a: String, b: String) -> String" took 20ms to parse which is way too slow for such a small input. There are some optimisations I can do in the code that I know off, but it was way slower than I expected.

On the other hand for predictive parsing I can not simply use their grammar as is. It seems it will need some manual changes to the grammar first. ANTLR must be doing some transformations on their grammar 1st before generating the parser.

Down the bottom of this grammar file for Kotlin is the same the number example above:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spec/blob/release/grammar/src/main/antlr/KotlinLexer.g4

I've read ANTLR can parse the full Java standard library in under 1 second. I might have a long way to go.

**Edit: (29/04/2022)** After more research, I found that the initial grammar (for number) has no problems for a predictive parser, I just needed more look-ahead.

Comment: Been trying to find an answer on google. The process to remove left recursion I understand, but having trouble on finding info about left factoring. That could be the missing piece of the puzzle I need to understand.

Comment: The procedure for left-factoring is pretty obvious. What might not be obvious is that (1) it's a heuristic, not an algorithm; there's no guarantee that repetitive application will produce a completely left-factored grammar; and (2) it's undecidable whether a particular grammar can be left-factored.

Comment: So it is more of a manual task for the user supplying the grammar?

Comment: Basically. In general, predictive parsers are not powerful enough to parse most useful languages. They are certainly powerful enough to *recognise* regular languages --and your language is regular-- but parsing goes beyond recognition because the essence of parsing is the parse, which describes what the parts are and how the relate to each other. That's why it's called partsing (the "t" vanished centuries ago because it's hard to pronounce.)

Comment: Normally, we don't bother with parsing things like numbers because the internal structure of the number is not important to parsing the text in which it appears. (More accurately, there are standard functions which efficiently parse a number and reduce it to an internal representation.) So a regex will work fine and any regex can be turned into a deterministic grammar. But that's not good enough for parsing programs.

Comment: I'm not specifically after parsing numbers its just an example. I am actually parsing Kotlin, but the performance I get for the current backtracking parser is not very good at the moment. Have a look if u like: https://github.com/clinuxrulz/parse-bolt/blob/main/src/kotlin/parser.rs . I wanted to copy the grammar as is from their website and hopefully use it with a predictive parser, but it looks like some of their grammar will need post-processing for using the predictive parser. Their grammar file is in ANTLR format, ANTLR 4 probably has some magic tricks I am unaware of.

Comment: It's likely there's no algorithm, but that does not mean one cannot use heuristic search, automated at that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm gonna stick to PEG and modify my own grammars for now where I need the performance. I haven't got the energy at the moment to look into heuristic search optimisations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going with rici's comment that there is no algorithm to guarantee full left factoring of any grammar. However there are heuristic search methods.

I'm gonna stick to PEG and modify my own grammars when I need the performance. And optimise my backtracking parsing combinator as much as possible as it can handle more types of grammars and might still be useful.